# change activitiy from fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I want to change activity(MainActivity -> MapActivity) in fragment(LookFragment) button.

LookFragment is in MainActivity FrameLayout.

This is LookFragment.kt

'''
class LookFragment : Fragment() {

```
lateinit var binding: FragmentLookBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentLookBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    binding.lookBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, MapActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    return binding.root
}
```

}

'''

When I press the button in the fragment to start Mapactivity then the app shut down.

Comment: Can you post the error log that appears in the debug console?

Comment: oh...I find that i didn't add MapActivity in manifest.... Thank u